# Match function in Excel returns N/A

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match

I have the following 3 columns in my excel sheet. The dates in column A (DateTime) are in the same format as column N(DateTime2) :

**Example of Excel matrix**

[image: Example of excel matrix]

The data are a lot, so I can't check it one by one. I tried to use match command in order to identify which date from column N(DateTime2) exist in column A(DateTime). I used the following command:

```
=MATCH(N2;$A$2:$A$5849;0)
```

I used autofill and as a result I got only first value as a number (which means that it exists), and the rest as N/A ..which is wrong. As you can see the value 1/1/16 3:00 exist in both columns.

I tried then to use the function VLOOKUP and I wrote the following command:

```
=VLOOKUP(N2;$A$2:$A$5849;1;FALSE)
```

I got the same outcome.. I checked one random value `(1/1/16 3:00)` to check if the two cells with the same value are equal using the command : `=A3=N5` and I got TRUE ..which means that the two cells are matching.

What do you think? What is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check that either both columns are numeric values formatted as dates or both columns contain text.

If you imported the data, sometimes different characters are used for <kbd>Space</kbd>. Try a find and replace (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>). Enter a <kbd>Space</kbd> character in both the "Find what:" and "Replace with:" fields.